Archlinux - pageflip timeout after update
I am using archlinux and after last update, when i have an heavy python script running via cli and some opened page in firefox, I get the GUI frozen and I have to reboot the system.
I don't know how/where to start
this is the output of jourtanctl -b -1, last line show the error
kernel: wlp6s0: AP 98:da:c4:b7:0d:78 changed bandwidth, new used config is 2412.000 MHz, width 2 (2422.000/0 MHz)
systemd[646]: drkonqi-coredump-pickup.service: Service reached runtime time limit. Stopping.
systemd[646]: drkonqi-coredump-pickup.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
systemd[646]: drkonqi-coredump-pickup.service: Consumed 39ms CPU time, 138.9M memory peak.
kscreenlocker_greet[3241]: qt.gui.imageio: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
plasmashell[893]: file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.keyboardindicator/contents/ui/main.qml:61:13: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
rtkit-daemon[728]: Supervising 9 threads of 6 processes of 1 users.
kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting rcs0 for preemption time out
kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] kwin_wayland[693] context reset due to GPU hang
kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:859ffffb, in kwin_wayland [693]
kernel: sched: RT throttling activated
kwin_wayland[693]: kwin_wayland_drm: Pageflip timed out! This is a kernel bug


what GPU do you have? this seems to be a consistent, kernel-level issue with nvidia(and some intel) cards

@juliethefoxcoon CPU =  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz, GPU = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

Have you tried using X11 instead of Wayland? Wayland is much newer and arguably suffers from more bugs yet to be fixed

@PonJar during the installation I had some issues with dual monitor (I am not an expert so could be some misconfiguration). How can I move from Wayland to Xorg?

You haven’t told us which desktop you are using but it looks like KDE. KDE and LXQt use something called sddm to log in. On the login page of that you can choose between various Xorg and Wayland sessions. I assume it’s similar with other login screens
